# Executing a second class by button click

Tags: java, user-interface

I have two classes, one is a GUI program and the other is an index writer program. 
The GUI program uses a `JFileChooser` to select directories and display them in the text fields.
The index writer is supposed to take the directories in the text fields and read from one (document location) and write into the other (index location).
I want to run the index writer program by the click of a button (indexfbuton) in the gui program.
I have been able to get the directories to display in the text field but when I click the button to run the index writer class, I get some errors, please how do I resolve this, thank you.

here is the GUI class:

```
package upload1;


import upload1.IndexFiles;

import java .awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.io.*;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.LongField;
import org.apache.lucene.document.StringField;
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.Date;




public class uploaad extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private static IndexFiles ind;


public static String uploaad_docsPath;
public static String uploaad_indexPath;


public static void main(String args[]) {

    ind  = new IndexFiles();

    uploaad sfc = new uploaad();
    sfc.setVisible(true);




        }
public uploaad() {
    super("Select File and Keyword");
    setSize(350, 200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


    final JTextField inputLine = new JTextField();
    inputLine.setColumns(22);
    JButton openButton = new JButton("Open");
    JButton indexButton = new JButton ("Index");
    final JButton indexfButton = new JButton("Index Files");
    JLabel keyword =  new JLabel("Enter Index Destination");
     final JTextField inputLine1 = new JTextField();
    inputLine1.setColumns(22);
    final JLabel statusbar = 
            new JLabel("Output of your selection will go here");



    openButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public  void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

          JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
          chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
          int option = chooser.showOpenDialog(uploaad.this);
          if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
              File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
              inputLine.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());
              uploaad_docsPath = inputLine.getText();


          }
          else {
            statusbar.setText("You canceled.");
          }


          }
        public  String uploaad_docsPath(){
          return inputLine.getText();}
      });


    indexButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ap) 
        {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
              chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
              int option = chooser.showOpenDialog(uploaad.this);
              if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                  File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                  inputLine1.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());
                  uploaad_indexPath = inputLine1.getText();

              }

              else {
                statusbar.setText("You canceled.");
              }

            }

        public  String uploaad_indexPath(){
          return inputLine.getText();}
          });


    indexfButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ap)
        {

            if (ap.getSource().equals( indexfButton) ) {

                IndexFiles.index(null);

            }
        }       

        });












    c.add(indexfButton);
    c.add(openButton);
    c.add(indexButton);
    c.add(inputLine);
    c.add(keyword);
    c.add(inputLine1);
    c.add(statusbar);
     }
     @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }






   }
```

Here is the indexfile class which i want to execute by the button event:

```
   package upload1;





   import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
   import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
   import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
   import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
   import org.apache.lucene.document.LongField;
   import org.apache.lucene.document.StringField;
   import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
   import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
   import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode;                                                                
   import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
   import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
   import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
   import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;

   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
   import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
   import java.nio.file.Files;
   import java.nio.file.Path;
   import java.nio.file.Paths;
   import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
   import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
   import java.util.Date;
   import java .awt.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;

   import javax.swing.*;

   import java.io.*;
   import java.util.Scanner;

   /** Index all text files under a directory.
   * <p>
   * This is a command-line application demonstrating simple Lucene          
   * Run it with no command-line arguments for usage information.
    */
   public class IndexFiles {


   public  IndexFiles() {}

   public static String uploaad_docsPath;
   public static String uploaad_indexPath;

   /** Index all text files under a directory. */
   public static void index(String[] args) {




     String usage = "java org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles"
             + " [-index C:/indexfolder1] [-docs C:/indexfolder] [-            
             + "This indexes the documents in C:/indexfolder, creating a 
              lucene index         
             + "in C:/indexfolder1 that can be searched with SearchFiles";






     String docsPath;
     String indexPath;

     docsPath = uploaad.uploaad_docsPath;
     indexPath = uploaad.uploaad_indexPath;

     //    docsPath = inputLine.getText();
     //    indexPath = inputLine;

     boolean create = true;
     for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++) {
     if ("-index".equals(args[i])) {
     indexPath = args[i+1];
     i++;
     } else if ("-docs".equals(args[i])) {
     docsPath = args[i+1];
     i++;
     } else if ("-update".equals(args[i])) {
     create = false;
      }
    }

    if (docsPath == null) {
    System.err.println("Usage: " + usage);
    System.exit(1);
    }

    final Path docDir = Paths.get(docsPath);
    if (!Files.isReadable(docDir)) {
    System.out.println("Document directory '" +docDir.toAbsolutePath()+ "'
     does not exist or is not readable, please check the path");       
     System.exit(1);
     }

    Date start = new Date();
    try {
    System.out.println("Indexing to directory '" + indexPath + "'...");

   Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(indexPath));
   Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
   IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);

    if (create) {
    // Create a new index in the directory, removing any
    // previously indexed documents:
    iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE);
    } else {
    // Add new documents to an existing index:
    iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
    } 

    // Optional: for better indexing performance, if you
    // are indexing many documents, increase the RAM
    // buffer.  But if you do this, increase the max heap
    // size to the JVM (eg add -Xmx512m or -Xmx1g):
    //
    // iwc.setRAMBufferSizeMB(256.0);

    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc);
    indexDocs(writer, docDir);

   // NOTE: if you want to maximize search performance,
   // you can optionally call forceMerge here.  This can be
   // a terribly costly operation, so generally it's only
   // worth it when your index is relatively static (ie
   // you're done adding documents to it):
   //
   // writer.forceMerge(1);

   writer.close();

   Date end = new Date();
   System.out.println(end.getTime() - start.getTime() + " total
    milliseconds");   

   } catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println(" caught a " + e.getClass() +
    "\n with message: " + e.getMessage());
   }



    }


     static void indexDocs(final IndexWriter writer, Path path) throws   
     IOException {
    if (Files.isDirectory(path)) {
    Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
     @Override
     public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)   
      throws IOException {
        try {
        indexDoc(writer, file, attrs.lastModifiedTime().toMillis());
        } catch (IOException ignore) {
         // don't index files that can't be read.
         }
       return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
       }
      });
      } else {
     indexDoc(writer, path, Files.getLastModifiedTime(path).toMillis());
     }
    }

   /** Indexes a single document */
   static void indexDoc(IndexWriter writer, Path file, long lastModified)   
   throws IOException {
   try (InputStream stream = Files.newInputStream(file)) {
   // make a new, empty document
   Document doc = new Document();

   // Add the path of the file as a field named "path".  Use a
   // field that is indexed (i.e. searchable), but don't tokenize 
   // the field into separate words and don't index term frequency
   // or positional information:
   Field pathField = new StringField("path", file.toString(),  
    Field.Store.YES);
    doc.add(pathField);

    // Add the last modified date of the file a field named "modified".
    // Use a LongField that is indexed (i.e. efficiently filterable with
    // NumericRangeFilter).  This indexes to milli-second resolution, which
    // is often too fine.  You could instead create a number based on
    // year/month/day/hour/minutes/seconds, down the resolution you require.
    // For example the long value 2011021714 would mean
    // February 17, 2011, 2-3 PM.
    doc.add(new LongField("modified", lastModified, Field.Store.NO));

    // Add the contents of the file to a field named "contents".  Specify a   
     Reader,
   // so that the text of the file is tokenized and indexed, but not stored.
   // Note that FileReader expects the file to be in UTF-8 encoding.
   // If that's not the case searching for special characters will fail.
   doc.add(new TextField("contents", new BufferedReader(new     
    InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));

     if (writer.getConfig().getOpenMode() == OpenMode.CREATE) {
      // New index, so we just add the document (no old document can be 
      there ):
     System.out.println("adding " + file);
     writer.addDocument(doc);
     } else {
     // Existing index (an old copy of this document may have been indexed)  
      so  
     // we use updateDocument instead to replace the old one matching the 
      exact        
     // path, if present:
     System.out.println("updating " + file);
     writer.updateDocument(new Term("C:/indexfolder1", file.toString()),
     doc);        

     }
      }
      }
    }
```

error messages:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException 
at upload1.IndexFiles.index(IndexFiles.java:80)             
at upload1.uploaad$3.actionPerformed(uploaad.java:141)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown   
Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown     source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown    source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown   Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please show your errors

Comment: Sorry but i already show the errors above: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException 
at upload1.IndexFiles.index(IndexFiles.java:80)             
at upload1.uploaad$3.actionPerformed(uploaad.java:141)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown   
Source)

Comment: So, have you **read** the stack trace? Have you examined what could be null, and thus cause a **NullPointerException** at line 80 of IndexFiles.java? What is the line 80?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the stack trace before ask?
You shouldn't pass the null as the parameter here:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ap)
        {

            if (ap.getSource().equals( indexfButton) ) {

                IndexFiles.index(null);

            }
        }
```

Try something like:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ap)
        {

            if (ap.getSource().equals( indexfButton) ) {

                IndexFiles.index(new String[]{});

            }
        }
```